# Ruby on Rails 6 loading module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know what is the right way to use a class with namespace in rails 6.
I have the follow, but it isn't working and I'm receiving the error:

"Uninitialized constant ProductsController::Operations Did you mean? ProductsController::Options"

```
#app/operations/create.rb
module Operations
  class Create
    def self.foo
      ...
    end
  end
end

#app/controllers/products_controller.rb

class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    Operations::Create.foo
  end
end
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: The file has to be in `app/modules/operations/create.rb`. You can swap out `modules` for really anything you like

Answer (score 1):

Your module should be inside of any folder. For example `app/services/operations/create.rb` (any name will work) with the same content you have:

```rb
module Operations
  class Create
    def self.foo
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

and call it `Operations::Create.foo`.

Also make sure you restart spring with `spring stop`.

Comment: Glad to hear that @LuísZambon. Can you accept my answer?